# Accessing a JSON file from HTML file to use objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I am making a to do list and i am trying to make a JSON file to link the objects for each Item on the to-do.

Im not really sure what I am meant to do and i am not sure what i am meant to look for with help.

```
// This is an example object
{
 "id":"01",
 "desc":"Do the To-Do List"
 },
```

I hope to be-able to view the objects I draw from the JSON file and show it as a table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show it as a table (and each object has the `id` and `desc` properties) loop over each object (I assume they're in an array of objects) and make a new row:

```js
const data = [{"id":"01","desc":"Do the To-Do List"},{"id":"02","desc":"Number Two!"},{"id":"03","desc":"A third option"}];
const table = document.getElementById("table");
data.forEach(({ id, desc }) => table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td><td>${desc}</td></tr>`);
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Desc</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```